# How to multiline replace different characters in vim

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-macros

i have this code snippet. I want to replace all the empty spaces with one space.
In IntelliJ i would simply multi-cursor, jump to the `--` use `option` + `shift` + `left arrow` then `right arrow` to select all the spaces and type a `space` which replaces them.

I'm new to vim and haven't found any solution that achieves this.

```
vim.opt.showmode = false                      -- we don't need to see things like -- INSERT -- anymore
vim.opt.showtabline = 2                       -- always show tabs
vim.opt.smartcase = true                      -- smart case
vim.opt.splitbelow = true                     -- force all horizontal splits to go below current window
vim.opt.splitright = true                     -- force all vertical splits to go to the right of current window
vim.opt.swapfile = false                      -- creates a swapfile
vim.opt.termguicolors = true                  -- set term gui colors (most terminals support this)
vim.opt.timeoutlen = 1000                     -- time to wait for a mapped sequence to complete (in milliseconds)
vim.opt.undofile = true                       -- enable persistent undo
vim.opt.writebackup = false                   -- if a file is being edited by another program (or was written to file while editing with another program), it
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my semi-fresh install of Intellij IDEA CE, the correct sequence would be:

```
<place cursor>
<option><option>
<down>
<down>
<down>
<down>
<down>
<down>
<down>
<down>
<down>
<option-shift-left>
<(option-shift-)right>
<space>
<escape>
```

In Vim, you could simply use a multi-cursor plugin, there are a few, or do it…

**With a substitution:**

```
vip
:'<,'>s/ \{2,}/ /<CR>
```

where…

- `vip` visually select the current "paragraph", see `:help v` and `:help text-objects`.
- `'<,'>` is the `:help :range` of lines on which to execute the following command. You can indicate a range explicitly or implicitly, by selecting the range of lines before entering command-line mode. This is what we did, here, and Vim inserted the corresponding range automatically: `'<,'>`.
- `s/ \{2,}/ /` is the substitution
- `\{2,}` matches 2 consecutive spaces or more.
- is, well… a single space.
- And `<CR>` is the Enter key.

**With the "dot formula":**

```
/ \{2,}<CR>
cgn<space>
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

where…

- `/ \{2,}<CR>` searches for the next sequence of 2 or more spaces. In this case, we are just setting the stage for the next commands.
- `cgn<space>` replaces the current or next search match with a `<space>`, see `:help c` and `:help gn`.
- The nine `.` repeat the previous command nine times, see `:help .`.

FWIW, I have [a custom mapping](https://gist.github.com/romainl/db725db7babc84a9a6436180cedee188) that makes it possible to use a count before `.`:

```
nnoremap . :<C-u>execute "norm! " . repeat(".", v:count1)<CR>
```

which shortens the command above quite a bit at the cost of counting the lines so YMMV:

```
/ \{2,}<CR>
cgn<space>
9.
```

Philosophical considerations:

- In a way, the "dot formula" is the opposite of multi-cursors: in one case you place the cursor *n* times and then perform the edit, while in the other you perform the edit and repeat it *n* times.
- Competent vimmers use search a lot for navigation and regular expressions tend to become a second nature. It feels weird at first to be so literal and deliberate about your edits, especially after decades of meaningless `<down>`s and `<left>`s, but it eventually grows on you.
- I would naturally go for the substitution.

Comment: I would've gone for the more sloppy `:s/ \+/ /g` which will replace one or more spaces with one space and that multiple times per line. Technically, it has the side effect of replacing all single spaces with a single space each but it's faster to type.